# How do I say "to go trick or treating" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do I say "to go trick or treating" in German? Here's my attempt:

> Ich gehe morgen mit meinen Freunden Trick or Treaten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der Einfachheit halber ist diese Antwort vorerst auf Deutsch.

Wie bereits in einem Kommentar angemerkt, existiert das Trick-or-Treating in Deutschland als Wort nicht. Was die Kinder an Halloween vor den Haustüren sagen, ist:

> Süßes oder Saures

Da aber im Deutschen die Verlaufsform nicht so einfach aus dem Substantiv gebildet werden kann wie im Englischen, existiert kein feststehender Begriff für das Halloween-Spektakel.

Als Alternative würde ich einfach hinzufügen, dass Halloween ist:

> Ich ziehe an Halloween mit meinen Freunden um die Häuser.